# jasmine-node tests aren't running

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have a file `word-count.js` that looks like this:

```
    function words(statement) {
        words = {}
        //some code here that does stuff
        return words
    }

    module.exports = words;
```

and a test suite file called `word-count_test.spec.js`

```
var words = require('./word-count');

describe("words()", function() {
  it("counts one word", function() {
    var expectedCounts = { word: 1 };
    expect(words("word")).toEqual(expectedCounts);
  });
  // more tests ... 
});
```

The two files are in the same folder, yet when I run

```
$ jasmine-node word-count.js


Finished in 0 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

Why aren't the tests working?

Comment: Whats the output when you run it `--verbose`?

Comment: @jmunsch Same, but gives off `undefined`. Problem?

Comment: Are there any asynchronous operations in the code you've removed?  Whenever I'm trying to test my asserts are firing I add something like `expect(1).toBe(2)` to make sure it fails as expected before even worrying about my application logic.

Comment: As far as I know, the `spec` file should be placed inside a `spec/` folder. Then running `jasmine-node spec/` should do the job.

Comment: I think I realized what the issue is. I can't believe I overlooked this. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running jasmine-node on the wrong file.

What I was doing (**incorrect**):

```
jasmine-node word-count.js
```

What I should be doing (**correct**):

```
jasmine-node word-count_test.spec.js
```